# Ошибка при вычислении площади треугольника

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задача:

> "Составить программу, которая
> вычисляет площадь треугольника, если
> человек задал длины трех сторон A,B,C.
> При вычислении использовать формулу
> Герона: S=sqrt(P(P-A)(P-cool.gif(P-C))
> , где Р — полупериметр. Перед
> вычислением площади про-верить,
> существует ли треугольник с заданными
> сторонами"

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ int a=12.0,b=7.0,c=8.0,p,s;
    if ((a>=(b+c))|(b>=(a+c))|(c>=(a+B)));
    else ("Impossible triagle");
p=(a+b+c)/2;
s=pow(p*(p-a)*(p-B)*(p-c),0.5);
```

Answer (score 3):

А что не получается?

За исключением B вместо b (на это компайлер должен ругнуться) и сообщения "Impossible triagle" в else (д.б. наоборот) приемлемо.

Ну, еще вместо `pow()` лучше попросту `sqrt()`.

**UPD**

```
double a=12.0,b=7.0,c=8.0,p,s;

if ((a>=(b+c))|(b>=(a+c))|(c>=(a+b))) { 
    printf("Impossible triagle\n"); 
} else { 
    p=(a+b+c)/2; 
    s=sqrt(p(p-a)(p-b)*(p-c)); 
    printf ("Triangle square is: %f\n",s); 
}
```

Comment: int a=12.0,b=7.0,c=8.0,p,s;
 if ((a>=(b+c))|(b>=(a+c))|(c>=(a+b)))
 { p=(a+b+c)/2;
  s=sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
 else "Impossible triagle";

выдает ошибку рядом с "Impossible triagle"

Comment: Нет, надо (черт, сразу не заметил 

1. отсутствие **printf** для "Impossible triagle" 

2. тип **double** int для переменных)


    double a=12.0,b=7.0,c=8.0,p,s;

    if ((a>=(b+c))|(b>=(a+c))|(c>=(a+b))) {
        printf("Impossible triagle\\n");
    } else {
        p=(a+b+c)/2; s=sqrt(p(p-a)(p-b)*(p-c));
        printf ("Triangle square is: %f\n",s);
    }

(Это уже хэш-коду. **Сделайте в конце концов нормальный форматер (*или выбросите его вообще**) для комментариев** Всавляю 4 пробела - нет эффекта.

Comment: AVP, только я успел проверить на DevC++, как Вы, впрочем всегда оперативно, ответили. Вот Вам еще +1. А теперь бы желательно парню еще сделать проверку на неотрицательные и ненулевые значения - как минимум.

Comment: Не получается нормально вводить комментарии - уползает за край экрана (вниз), рулером сдвигается, а при вводе символов обратно прыгает назад.
Отформатировать код не удается.

Comment: ага, скроллинг бесит, форматирования нет

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#pragma hdrstop
using namespace std;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
void rcout(char *string)              //Для вывода в консоли кириллицы
{
char new_string[255];
CharToOem(string,new_string);
cout<<new_string;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        double S,p,a,b,c;
        rcout("Введите а : ");
        cin>>a;
        rcout("Введите b: ");
        cin>>b;
        rcout("Введите c: ");
        cin>>c;
        p=(a+b+c)/2;
        S=sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
        cout<<"S = "<<S<<"\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вряд ли для данных занятий используют BCB. По своей памяти помню, при изучении C++ следующее требование: делать работу на MS Visual C++ , а там - Бог его знает :)

Comment: Только вместо system("pouse"); лучше все-таки сделать свое ожидание ввода (например через getch()). 

А то даже больно смотреть, как студентов учат **бездумно распылять** ресурсы системы.